# Python split string based on varying delimiters and join the result

Tags: python

I'm trying to split a string based on varying delimiters. For e.g.

```
Str_with_Delim1 = 'FirstPart_Delim1_SecondPart'
Str_with_Delim2 = 'FirstPart_Delim2_SecondPart'
```

Somewhere in the program i encounter a string `S` which can be either with `Delim1` or with `Delim2` which I want to get rid of and join the result. Something like below:

```
#example of what I'd like to achieve
''.join(S.split('_Delim1' or '_Delim2'))
#result of above split: 'FirstPart_SecondPart'
```

I can do it with few lines of `if-else` checks like so:

```
if '_Delim1' in  S:
    ''.join(S.split('_Delim1'))
else:
    ''.join(S.split('_Delim2'))
```

But I'm guessing if there's a better way to achieve this:
All the solutions I found on SO is related to splitting strings with Multiple Delimiters.

Can it be achieved more succinctly rather than making use of the `if-else` statements?

Comment: I know this works : `' '.join(S.split('_Delim1' if '_Delim1' in S else '_Delim2'))`

Comment: the `''.join(whatever.split(delim))` logic is weird; it's equivalent to just removing the delimiter -> `string.replace(delim1, '').replace(delim2, '')` works well enough

Comment: @StefanB to be honest it's not *that* weird. What you suggested is ***alot*** better when you have a single separator for example. Even two is reasonable as your example. What if you have a list of, say, 10 separators? The `re` solution provided in answers becomes more reasonable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [**`re.split()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) and [regular expression alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to split on both delimiters.

```
import re

''.join(re.split(r'_Delim1|_Delim2', S))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) method.

```py
import re
for s in ['FirstPart_Delim1_SecondPart', 'FirstPart_Delim2_SecondPart']:
    print(re.split('_Delim[12]_', s))
```

That produces

```
['FirstPart', 'SecondPart']
['FirstPart', 'SecondPart']
```

Answer (score 0):

So as i understand you want to replace some dynamic delimiter to single underlining?

So you need to use regex:

```
import re

s = 'FirstPart_Delim1_SecondPart'


# this pattern for your example
pattern = r'_Delim[0-9+]_'

# replace your custom delimiter to single underling
s = re.sub(pattern, '_', s)

# output will - FirstPart_SecondPar
print(s)
```

expression `_Delim[0-9+]_`  means that you can pass any number (not only 1 or 2) with "Delim" string and it will be work correct.

Also this method quite good because you don't need to convert string to list and back you will always work with string.